# Rigging a man pushing a cart?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, parent

Could someone please help me with how to build this guy pushing a cart? I've already tried, but with my limited knowledge of blenders, I'm not getting very far. The idea would be that the main driving force might be the hands. The handle area should move relative to the character's hands, up, down, back and forth as the cart rotates around the wheel axis. Here is the blend file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BI5jG5U0c1VFXwrxK0kIrHaA6fHHjXzb/view?usp=share_link (40mb)

[image: man and cart]

Comment: Hello and welcome! What have you tried? Please include the details of what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Harry, Thanks for the reply. A little difficult to say what ive tried, i feel like ive thrown every possible constraint at the setup lol ..  I have a bone chain with auto IK that starts from the wheels up to the handle (two bones) so this rotates the cart from the wheel axis. I then tried to constraint (child of) the child bone (at the handle) to the characters hand, both FK and IK bones ..

Comment: i can get the hand to move the cart around, however it seems the rotation is the biggest issue for me. I cant get the cart to rotate on the wheel axis based on the characters > hands movement. For example if he pushes down on the  handle .. the cart should rotate respectively down from the wheel axis. Thank again :)

Comment: I would create a simple cart rig and do it the other way around. Attach the cart handle like a weapon (sword, gun, etc.), to the character (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehywh.gif) -- I think the real challenge is getting him to walk with the car on a curve.

Comment: Ah! that gif is just teasing :p  I can't even get that far lol ... are you able to provide a copy of the blend file so i can study it? I'm very new to blender, so still trying to grasp the concepts! Thank you!

Comment: If anyone else is able to propose any suggestions, still trying to solve this one. Thank you!

Comment: Happy New Year. Yes, I can share the file. Just need to see if I can make a simple demo or upload this 40 MB somewhere.

Comment: Ah cool! Thanks. Really appreciated it :D

Comment: I'll post an answer but it will take some time. Meanwhile, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bcBrav5b3uRGdwa36W5WVXaJTItSc1hr/view?usp=sharing) is the file so you can already have a look. There is a little flaw. The root bone of the cart rig is not aligned with the global axis. It should be laying on the ground with Z pointing up to be more consistent. I couldn't fix it without destroying the animation. So be sure your rig is nice & clean before you do a serious animation ;-)